# Cassandra based graph database

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan

I am planning to use cassandra and graph database in my spring web project. After googling i found some open source graph database. Actually i was looking for some open source graph database that has good support of cassandra and so i found titan graph database. It seems good but its new and don't know how much efficient it is for real world application that has huge data and read/write operations.
So i want to know that

**1. Is there any more cassandra supported graph database?

2. Is titan good enough for real world web application with huge data and read/write operations?**

Comment: you'll get better answers if you are more specific with your question